# Equivalent regular grammar with minimum number of nonterminals

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

Given a set of terminal symbols $\Sigma=\{a,b\}$ and a set of nonterminal symbols $N=\{S,A,B\}$ with start symbol $S$, then the two following sets of production rules are equivalent:

- $S\to aA$
- $A\to aA$
- $A\to bB$
- $B\to aA$
- $B\to bB$
- $B\to \epsilon$

and

- $S\to aA$
- $A\to aA$
- $A\to bA$
- $A\to b$

They both match any string starting with $a$ and ending with $b$, but the second set of rules has only two nonterminals instead of three.
Is there a standard way to convert an arbitrary (regular) grammar to the equivalent grammar with the smallest number of non terminals?
I don't think this can be achieved by the rules for Chomsky normal form.

Answer (score 3):

A regular grammar corresponds directly to a finite automaton, mapping each non-terminal to a state. So this question is equivalent to asking how to minimize the number states in a finite automaton. Unfortunately, minimizing NFAs is hard. See, for example, [Gregor Gamlich, 2007](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000006001735).